# Inserting form into wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Ok, I created a form here:

http://kenzshop.com/trevcap.html

I took all the css from it, and added it to all the places that I can see that it is being called from within wordpress. There are MANY css files to this wordpress theme for some reason.

I then inserted the code (minus the css) to a page within wordpress. Here:

http://www.tkfinancialgroup.com/main/

But it is not functioning at all, also breaking the page. Not sure where to go from here.

[Solved] Just needed to finish it off by readjusting my inline styles, Thanks Everyone.

Ken

Comment: I looked inside the html code of your wordpress page, most of the codes are "commented", including the input boxes for name and email. It will definitely not show up.

Comment: I think that may be the issue there, it seems wordpress isn't handling the commenting out very well, I'll try deleting the commented out areas and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, after deleting the commented out area, a little bit of the functionality came back, still way off though.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the specific styles you used inside the form, pick only the css you used there, and include the css inside the `<style type="text/css">... put your styles here...</style>` before your html codes.

Comment: I actually created a custom field as described here: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-embed-css-in-your-posts-with-a-custom-field and added all the css, as well as adding it all to multiple css files that i could see where it was pulling from. I did as you suggested though, and it made no difference. I don't believe wordpress allows adding style in that way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is, you insert the code directly in to wordpress post right? Then word press will convert some new line character in to

for example the code

```
a = function (){

   alert('this is a');

}
```

will be

```
<p>
a = function (){</p>
<p>
   alert('this is a');</p>

}
```

and not correct
So I suggest that you should use an iframe to insert your form to a post Or directly insert it to page template

You can also try to reduce enter from your code, an empty line will be encode into

Comment: Then he should insert it using the CODE VIEW, also available in the posting area, so the html codes will remain the same.

Comment: Wordpress will try to encode anything in code view also, you can try to view source from your browser to see what happend

Comment: you can also try to reduce enter in your code `head.appendChild(style);
setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);</p>
<p>var mce_preload_checks = 0;
function mce_preload_check(){
    if (mce_preload_checks>40) return;`

Comment: You are talking way over my head Trinh, I'm still a noob..sorry :(

Comment: Here, when you insert code (javascript) with some *new line* in wordpress post, wordpress will replace new line with a paragraph (or <br/>) whit will make your script error and cannot run

Answer (score 0):

You have no form fields in second link:

```
<form action="http://tkfinancialgroup.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a0fe2509d571ceb4fa7b4a885&id=faeefd3cd3" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/guide.jpg" width="396" height="251" alt="capture"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="launchcommentsblock"/>
    <div class="aclear"/>
</form>
```

The first one is ok though:

```
<form action="http://tkfinancialgroup.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a0fe2509d571ceb4fa7b4a885&id=faeefd3cd3" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.tkfinancialgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/guide.jpg" width="396" height="251" alt="capture"/>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<input type="text" value="Name" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" style="width: 117px; height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 115px; left: 251px; "/>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<input type="email" value="Email" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" style="width: 117px; height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 142px; left: 251px; "/>
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none; "/>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none; "/>
</div>
<div class="clear">
<input type="submit" value="" name="get access now" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="position: absolute; bottom: 123px; left: 329px; width: 48px; height: 14px; opacity: 0; "/>
</div>
</form>
```

Fixing this should fix functionality.

Comment: Thanks h4b0, Wordpress was doing it's own thing with my commented out areas, i removed them which brought a bit of functionality back, it seems the styling isnt being applied now though.